# JQuery / JavaScript , dynamically storing / applying functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, prototype

I currently have a piece of code as follow:.

```
var nextSibling = $(this.parentNode).next();
```

what I would like to do is potentially change the next() function to prev(), depending on the keypress. (I expect this to be an input element in a table).

How do I put the next() / prev() functions into variables (I am guessing you access it through some prototype object, but I am not sure which one).

```
if (keypressRight){ 
    var nexOrPrev =  SomeObject.prototype.next
}else{
    var nextOrPrev =  SomeObject.prototype.prev
}
```

Then to call it , I assume I would do the following :

```
 var nextSibling = $(this.parentNode).nextOrPrev()
```

Does that look like the correct way of doing things? I am open to suggestions of better ways. (I saw somewhere else suggesting using apply for the function call, but I don't currently see any benefit in using this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to call function on a jQuery object. Try this:

```
var funcName = keypressRight ? 'next' : 'prev';
var nextSibling = $(this.parentNode)[funcName]();
```

Answer (score 1):

you may write

```
var nextOrPrev =  SomeObject.prototype[keypressRight?"next":"prev"];
```

using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

and this can be done also for

```
$(this.parentNode)[keypressRight?"next":"prev"]();
```